# Moodle 3.5 Ajax returning plain text vs JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, moodle

I am trying to figure out why I am getting different results accross to different Moodle 3.5 installations.

I have the following jquery ajax code pulling a json file:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "terms.json",
    success: function(data){        

        var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);

    }
});
```

In my clients version of Moodle, when I run this code it returns the json file, but as plain text and not a JSON object. I understand this is because of the header, which is set to: text/plain; charset=utf-8.

However, I did a fresh local install of Moodle 3.5 and when I run the same code, I get an actual JSON object returning back to me with the following header type:
application/json.

I understand this might not be the desired implementation, but I am just wondering why I am getting two different results. Is there a setting in Moodle I am missing or is this more of a server thing?

Is there anyway I can force Moodle to return a JSON object?

Thank you

Comment: since it's a static JSON file it could be to do with MIME Type settings on the webserver